# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_AND

Tags: php, ini

I want to get variables defined in `php.ini` file and below is the line to do that.

```
$settings = parse_ini_file("php.ini");
```

It gives error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_AND in path/of/file on line 218
```

That line in `php.ini` is

```
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
```

I think this is due to word `and`. But this line is a comment. So why is it giving this error?

Edit : Removing `and` from line in `php.ini` file solved issue. I don't know why it was causing problem. I changed line to

```
; <? n ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
```

Answer (score 0):

You made something wrong, I guess you included the file somewhere.

`<?php` tags in comments (or wherever) will **not** start a *code* section in an ini file meaning that `parse_ini_file()` will never start a PHP parser.

Steps to reproduce:

*test.ini*:

```
;<?php and ?>
a=1
```

*test.php*:

```
<?php

var_dump(parse_ini_file('test.ini'));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  'a' =>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

You see it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in `php.ini`, but somewhere about line 218 of your source file.

Comment: It was due to something in `php.ini` file. See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I dont see any comment lines
add `//` at the start of line or  put that text in `/* comment goes here*/`
these brackets!

Comment: For .ini files, `;` denotes the start of comment.

Comment: Those aren't valid ini comment. The line in the question has a semicolon `;` which is a comment